Cannot install Gecko for Wine (fixme:file:NtLockFile error)
I ran an application in Wine, and it gave me some error/warning about Wine not having Gecko installed. It directed me to this page:
https://gitlab.winehq.org/wine/wine/-/wikis/Gecko
Following instructions, I downloaded the most recent, 64-bit version of Gecko from that page (2.47.4, I'm on Wine 9.20).
However, when I try to run it using
wine msiexec /i /home/jack/Downloads/wine-gecko-2.47.4-x86.msi

or even just wine [the msi file] directly, I get:
0148:fixme:file:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0148:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0148:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 5)
0148:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 5)

Ubuntu 24.04, Wine 9.20
